Save question in more than one list
Simple suggestion.
It could be nice to have the possibility to save a question or an answer in more than just one created list.

I appreciate your suggestions, my downvote is solely to indicate that I don't think this feature request should be prioritized above the myriad of what I think is more important work.

Which makes "Voting on meta is different"... kind of an understatement. No its random. Completely random.
